# Assets not being served by assets pipeline in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, assets, ruby-on-rails-2

I am migrating a big application from Rails 2 to Rails 3.
I added some images to app/assets/images. i.e. app/assets/images/key.png

If I go to `http://localhost:3000/assets/key.png` I dont see the image. In the server log I see that it was not found and one of the controller started to process the request.

```
Started GET "/assets/key.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-19 17:44:31 -0300
Served asset /key.png - 404 Not Found (49ms)
Processing by DfcController#index as PNG
  Parameters: {"path"=>"assets/key"}
```

In development.rb I have the lines:

```
config.assets.debug = true
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

And in application.rb I have the lines:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in your development.rb. Because during development, your rails application server acts as your web server too and should serve the static assets.

Comment: I dont think so. If I set it to true the assets will only come from public folder. Anyway, I tried it with no luck.

Comment: It's interesting that the request goes to the controller. Have you added some wild-card route using 'match'? Also, is your assets debug setting set in development.rb - "config.assets.debug = true" ?